# using adapter.setDropDownViewResource produces syntax error

Tags: android, spinner

I have reviewed several examples of how to set up a spinner in my program and they all use the same format that I am using, yet eclipse says that it is a syntax error, specifically: "Syntax error on token "setDropDownViewResource", identifier expected after this token. Additionally it says that the statement that sets the spinner adapter expects a variable declaratorid after the token "adapter"

here is the code block in question:

```
Spinner tipPercent = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tip_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
        R.array.tip_percentage, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `adapter` ArrayAdapter instance as:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
        R.array.tip_percentage, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```